# Inheritance between activities in Android

Tags: android, inheritance, android-activity

I am having trouble applying the concept of inheritance to Android Activities - eg. 
`ActivityA extends Activity` and 
`ActivityB extends ActivityA` , then if I launch with ActivityB then onCreate() method for **both** Activities (A then B) is called .

My question is, in typical Java , onCreate from ActvityA should be over-ridden - but onCreate is rather behaving as a constructor even though its a function. How does inheritance work in Android, esp. wrt other functions like onPause(),onResume etc. ?

EDIT: I also noticed that ActivityA may have many abstract methods called in its onCreate() whose definitions are provided in ActivityB. How does this work ?

Comment: `esp. wrt other state functions ?` please define that sentence. I don't get it.

Comment: +1 for nice question.!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have your base Activity and then extend it like so `Activity` -> `Activity A` it means that when your onCreate of `Activity A` is called and you call `super.onCreate();` then the `onCreate()` method of the original `Activity` is also called.

If you then extend `Activity A` into `Activity B` the calls work like so...

`Activity B.onCreate()` - `super.onCreate();`-->`Activity A.onCreate()` - `super.onCreate()`-->`Activity.onCreate()`.

Its not a constructor, its a method thats called to create the `Activities`. If you then extend them from other `Activities` its superclass is going to be called via its `super` method. It doesn't mean that the `Activities` you have inherited from are going to be created too. `Activity B` will be your created `Activity`.

**EDIT:** [This page](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) on the Android Developer website is very useful as it visually explains the Android Activity lifecycle.

Comment: I would also like to point out in addition that the reason for `onCreate` to be instead of constructor, is that on orientation change, the object shouldn't be reconstructed.

Comment: ahh.. how did i miss super.onCreate() thanks a lot and could you also explain how the abstract methods work (i've edited the question)

Comment: @AndroidLearnMachine what methods are you talking about?

Comment: What I meant was, there are abstract methods in ActivityA which are called in the onCreate() of ActivityA . These methods are defined only in ActivityB, how does that happen ? Are they invoked with the definition in ActivityB ?

Comment: If you were to create some methods in ActivityB and call them in ActivityB's onCreate method then if you created an ActivityA Activity (without extending ActivityB) then these methods would not be called.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as a typical java function onCreate should have been inherited but it doens't get : why? - because it's not just a method, it's a life cycle stage.

AFAIK, Activity is not just a java class but it's a special type of a JAVA Class which has it's own life cycle and Life Cycle stages are meant to be called each and every time you use that class/activity even if you have declared or not those methods onCreate(), onPause() etc gets called for sure.

So every time the base activity will get created and destroyed. That's it's nature.

If you have problem with that you can try using Abstract classes, Interfaces and any other public class to have common code inherited in your all activities.

Answer (score 0):

> How does Inheritance work in Android?

There nothing special about Android. It works exactly as it should.

#### Example?

Lets create a `BaseActivity` which listens to a `BroadcastReceiver` ([SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)).
So common functions are,

1. Register a `BroadcastReceiver` in `onCreate()`
2. Unregister a `BroadcastReceiver` in `onDestroy()`

> BaseClass:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private WifiScanReceiver wifiScanReceiver; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle sis)
    {
        super.onCreate(sis);   
        // Don't call setContentView() because no layout is needed              
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(wifiScanReceiver);
    }

    private void registerMyReceiver(){
         wifiScanReceiver = new WifiScanReceiver();
         registerReceiver(wifiScanReceiver, new 
         IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
         manager.startScan();
    }

}
```

> Child class:

```
public class BlahBlahActivity extends BaseActivity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      // this will call BaseActvity method which will call AppcompatActivty method
        setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
    }
}
```